# Unique array values in Mongoose

Tags: arrays, unique, mongoose

Currently trailing out Mongoose and MongoDB for a project of mine but come across a segment  where the API is not clear.

I have a Model which contains several keys and documents, and one of those keys os called `watchList`. This is an array of ID's that the user is watching, But I need to be sure that these values stay unique.

Here is some sample code:

```
var MyObject = new Mongoose.Schema({
    //....
    watching : {type: Array, required: false},
    //....
});
```

So my question is how can I make sure that the values pushed into the array only ever store one, so making the values unique, can i just use `unique: true` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to do this in mongoose is to call the underlying Mongo operator ([mentioned by danmactough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642747/3617)). In mongoose, that'd look like:

```
var idToUpdate, theIdToAdd; /* set elsewhere */
Model.update({ _id: idToUpdate }, 
             { $addToSet: { theModelsArray: theIdToAdd } }, 
             function(err) { /*...*/ }
);
```

Note: this functionality requires mongoose version >= 2.2.2

Comment: can *theIdToAdd* be an array, such as `["ID1", "ID2"]` ?

Comment: I guess u could use $each for that.

Comment: @RoberPitt excellent point... theIdToAdd cannot be an array. If you do that, the item to be inserted will be that array. I'm trying to find a way to solve this :-(

Comment: If theIdToAdd is array use $each
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#addtoset-modifiers

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [Mongo documentation on the $addToSet operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$addToSetand$each).

Comment: So, $addToSet will add a new element into the array if it already doesn't contain a duplicate. Is there a way (e.g. creating a unique index), which will ensure there never are duplicated in an array? Basically, I want a Set instead of a Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is an object model for mongodb, so one option is to treat the document as a normal javascript object.

```
MyModel.exec(function (err, model) {
   if(model.watching.indexOf(watchId) !== -1) model.watching.push(watchId);

   model.save(...callback);
});
```

Although, I do agree that mongoose should have some support for this built in the form of a validator for the [collection document reference feature](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)-- especially because most of the time you want to add only unique references.

Comment: This won't work if the set was added to the model by a concurrent operation, and in your example, you will be checking if the set exists in a stale copy of the model. Hence needing an enforced database level unique index.

Answer (score 0):

### That's how you can do it using Mongoose,

> IF your upcoming value is an Array

```
Model
    .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: yourID }, 
    { $addToSet: { watching: { $each: yourWatchingArr } } },
    function(err) { /*...*/ }
    );
```

> IF your upcoming value is a string

```
Model
    .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: yourID }, 
    { $addToSet: { watching: yourStringValue } },
    function(err) { /*...*/ }
    );
```