# Embedded array as a Set (in the mathematica sense) in a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, insert, indexing, unique-index

The "schema" for objects I am putting in a collection goes something like this:

```
{
    name : "Niranjan", //<--key
    children : ["Suraj", "kalidas", "Suraj"]
}
```

But I wanted to ensure that children would be treated as a set - in the example above I wanted Mongo to not accept the record because "Suraj" appear twice in the array.

I tried creating a unique index over name and children

```
db.folks.ensureIndex({name:1,children:1},{unique:true})
```

What this does, however, is that it makes a globally unique index over any child name + folk name. That is if I DO NOT also have a unique index on name I will be able todo the  following:

```
db.folks.insert({name:'p',children:['c1','c2']})
db.folks.insert({name:'p',children:['c3']})
```

because p+c1, p+c2 and p+c3 are distinct. If I tried to insert the following:

```
db.folks.insert({name:'p',children:['c4','c1']})
```

then I will get

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.folks.$name_1_children_1  dup key: { : "p", : "c1" }
```

Is there a way to achieve this without doing a 
[check during insertion as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640233/unique-array-values-in-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640233/unique-array-values-in-mongoose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique indexes will act the way you expect in a future release of MongoDB:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068

For now, you'll need to check for uniqueness in your application before inserting.

Incidentally, when you're updating documents, you can use $addToSet instead of $push, to enforce uniqueness:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSetand%24each

Comment: @that was what I linked to too in my question .. I didn't want to do that and have another process insert stuffs into my collection without using that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you want to check on insertion. Check it in your application; MongoDB can't enforce it for you.

Comment: @Jesse, does mongo support (or has future plans to support) something comparable to a "trigger" in that case so that I could enforce such constraints or even more general ones (at the cost of speed and complexity in the face of sharding and distributed nature in general)?

Comment: I didn't give you a good answer before. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068 , what you want to do is planned in a future release. I've edited my answer to include that.

However, beyond unique indexes, there probably won't be more sophisticated constraints or triggers in MongoDB. To use MongoDB, change your thinking to expect less logic in the database server than you're used to in a SQL server. Do your business logic in your application, and use MongoDB to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Hey @UstamanSangat, is this answer complete or do you need more info?

Comment: I will be looking forward to the unique index improvements in Mongo so that I can have Set semantics. Thanks